# Resizing jpeg image after conversion from bitmap does not work

Tags: delphi, bitmap, type-conversion, jpeg

I am converting a `bitmap` to `jpeg` and want to display the result in an image using various scales.  I am using the following code which works fine.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Bmp: TBitmap;
  Jpg: TJPEGImage;
begin
  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  Bmp.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
  Jpg := TJPEGImage.Create;
  try
    Bmp.LoadFromFile('0C310060.bmp');
    Jpg.Assign(Bmp);
    Jpg.SaveToFile('0C310060.jpg');
    Image1.Picture.Assign(Jpg);
    TJPEGImage(Image1.Picture.Graphic).Scale := jsEighth;
  finally
    Jpg.Free;
    Bmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I have no need for the `jpeg` file on disk.  However, if I eliminate the line `Jpg.SaveToFile('0C310060.jpg')` I get an access violation.  **Why?**  What does `Jpg.SaveToFile` do behind the scene to prevent the access violation?

Comment: Pretty sure that's just the way it is :)  You can save to a `TMemoryStream` in place of `SaveToFile`.

Comment: if you remove that line, which line produces the AV?

Comment: "jsFullSize" does not cause an AV so I would think this to be related with compression. Indeed if you call `TJPEGImage(Image1.Picture.Graphic).Compress;` before scaling, then there are no errors. Since I don't know what I'm doing, though, I can't tell if this is a bug or expected behavior.

Comment: In any case, I think that is the answer to your question: saving to file most probably internally compresses the image.

Comment: @Nasreddine This line causes the error: TJPEGImage(Image1.Picture.Graphic).Scale := jsEighth;

Comment: Both your suggestions from John and Sertac work and take about the same time to execute.  Thanks.